# MMDrawerController example app view initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, mmdrawercontroller

I'm a newbie to iOS development. MMDrawerControllerKitchenSink turned out to be a great example of how to make an app. It is an example app that uses MMDrawerController.

I cannot find any initialization of the view property of the MMExampleCenterTableViewController. There is the viewDidLoad method but the first line with the view property is

```
_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

And there is no alloc / init of the view in all the upper hierarchy of this method. Can anyone, please, tell me how the view property is actually gets initialized in the MMDrawerControllerKitchenSink?

Thank you.

Comment: What you want to do actually ? Here is information : https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController#creating-a-drawer-controller

Comment: @AshishKakkad I want to understand how the example app is made for educational purposes. I know this wiki. The question is actually about the MMDrawerControllerKitchenSink app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the MMExampleCenterTableViewController is the initial view it is probably getting initialized in the `AppDelegate.m`.

Comment: Your answer pushed me further in exploring the code. And yes I realized that the view was initialized in another place. Here https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController/blob/master/MMDrawerController/MMDrawerController.m#L409